# Swift: unwind segue doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, unwind-segue

I'm stuck with unwind segue that doesn't work for some reason, I do everything as described in tutorial: cntrl drag to exit and select unwind action from another controller (please see gif attached). When I run it on my iphone and tap Cancel, nothing happens.
[image: Description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the view controller you're trying to unwind from is already the bottom of the `UINavigationController`'s stack, so it's not going to do anything when the unwind is called.

If that `UINavigationController` is being called modally, call

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

within the view controller where the button is being pressed.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. The view controller's placement on the storyboard doesn't determine where it is in the stack. That will be determined at runtime. 

I'm sure `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` did dismiss the view controller, but it's not because you got the unwind segue to work. It's because this is an alternative way to dismiss a view controller. Unless you also removed the unwind segue, it's probably still just sitting there never being called.