# Unwind segue not dismissing view

Tags: swift, segue, unwind-segue

The Issue:

Unwind segue not dismissing view, even though it works.

Scenario:

I have an "add product" screen, and when the product is added, I fire up unwind segue, which in turn shows a popup: "New Product added".

The Facts:
1) Product is successfully added to Database
2) the popup "Product added" is shown in the `@IBAction` of the unwind segue in target, and it appears
3) The popup "Product Added" is shown over the `AddProductScreen` view

Picture 1: Existence of Unwind segue
[image]

`@IBAction` located in target view:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromAddProductViewSuccess(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
    {
        AlertManager.showTimedAlert(title: "Success", message: "New Product added", timeShowing: 1, callingUIViewController: self)
    }
```

Function being called in `AddProductView` for registering the product:

```
private func registerProductAndPerformSegue(productToRegister prod: Product)
    {
        self.registerProduct(prodToRegister: prod)
        Constants.logger.debug("New product registered")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwind_from_add_product_success", sender: self)

    }
```

In the "Add Product View", after "Confirm" is clicked, an alert shows with "Are you sure?" and then you are prompt to click "Yes" or "No".

This is the code for the alert:

```
AlertManager.ShowAlert(controllerToShowAlert: self, alertTitle: LocalizationStrings.Products.ADD_PRODUCT_TITLE, alertText: LocalizationStrings.Products.ADD_PRODUCT_CONFIRMATION,
                                           alertStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert,
                                           leftButtonAction: UIAlertAction(title: LocalizationStrings.YES_TEXT, style: .default, handler:
                                            {
                                                (action: UIAlertAction!) in

                                                let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

                                                if let user = user
                                                {
                                                    let product : Product = Product(name: name!, price: Double(price!)!, currency: "USD", description: desc!,
                                                                                    location: "USA", ownerID: user.uid, ownerName: user.displayName!, uniqueID: "", mainImageURL: nil, category: category)


                                                    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(product.getUniqueID()).child("pic0.jpg")
                                                    if let mainChosenImage = self.selectedImageToUpload
                                                    {
                                                        Constants.logger.debug("Product picture chosen")
                                                        if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mainChosenImage, 0.2)
                                                        {
                                                            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil)
                                                            {
                                                                (StorageMetaData, error) in
                                                                if error != nil
                                                                {
                                                                    Constants.logger.error("Add Product: Couldn't store image in database!")
                                                                    return
                                                                }

                                                                self.mainImageURL = StorageMetaData?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                                                                if let urlString = self.mainImageURL
                                                                {
                                                                    product.AddImageURLToProduct(URL: urlString)
                                                                    self.registerProductAndPerformSegue(productToRegister: product)
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            Constants.logger.error("Couldn't convert uploaded image to UIImageJPEGRepresentation")
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        Constants.logger.debug("Product picture NOT chosen")
                                                        self.registerProductAndPerformSegue(productToRegister: product)
                                                    }
                                                }
                                           }),

                                           rightButtonAction: UIAlertAction(title: LocalizationStrings.NO_TEXT, style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                                            print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
                                           }))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How did you segue to the Add Produce Screen? Was it a push or a present?

Comment: I am using "push"

Comment: Right, it's pretty hard to know exactly what's going on without looking at the project, but I'd say you want to start pulling stuff out until you've got the barebones push and unwind working. Pretty good sample here to go back to basics and get stuff working https://stackoverflow.com/a/40248196/3320342

Comment: I followed it, and the difference is that I am manually activating the unwind segue by identifier, since I do not have a physical button for "Add the Product", since after I click "Confirm upload", there's another popup with "Are you sure? YES/NO" and only on "Yes" it should fire it up

Comment: I added a part of my function :) Please see update

Answer (score 0):

Without more details about your Storyboard setup and your code, it's hard to tell what the exact problem is. 
But I'll assume that you have two view controllers and I will try to guide you through the steps to do an `unwindSegue` and you can check if you maybe have missed something.

Assuming that you have two view controllers: `FirstViewController and`AddProductViewController`, and`AddProductViewController` is presented using a push segue.

Inside `FirstViewController` you have:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromAddProductViewSuccess(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    AlertManager.showTimedAlert(title: "Success", message: "New Product added", timeShowing: 1, callingUIViewController: self)
}
```

Then, You connect your "save" or "add" button from `AddProductViewController` to `unwindFromAddProductViewSuccess:` action method.

You can also connect your "save" or "add" button to `SecondViewController` to debug that the segue is being called:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController { 
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let uiBarButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem else {
            print("There is no UIBarButtonItem sender")
            return
        }

        if saveButton == uiBarButtonItem {
            print("save button tapped")
        }
        print("A segue with an identifier \(segue.identifier ?? "") was called.")
    }
}
```

Assuming that you don' have a bar button item and want to call `unwidnSegue` manually, maybe after the user taps on an `UIAlertController` action, then you can do something like this:

```
@IBAction func orderButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Order Placed!", message: "Thank you for your order.\nWe'll ship it to you soon!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
    (_)in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMenu", sender: self)
    })

    alert.addAction(OKAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

There are also some cases when the UIViewController that you are trying to unwind from is at the bottom of the `UINavigationController` stack, in this case, calling `unwindSegue` will not do anything. There was a similar question related to that before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954996/swift-unwind-segue-doesnt-work).

I hope that this info can help you figure out the problem.

Comment: I have checked the updated code in the original post, and I have a doubt related to threading. Can you check if maybe `registerProductAndPerformSegue` is called on a background thread? Updating the UI generally on background threads can lead to unexpected behavior. As a quick check, can you try switching to the main queue before calling `registerProductAndPerformSegue`? Just call `registerProductAndPerformSegue` inside the callback of `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: Can you try replacing this line:
`self.registerProductAndPerformSegue(productToRegister: product)`
with

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.registerProductAndPerformSegue(productToRegister: product)
}`

This will guarantee that the call for `unwindSegue` will happen on the main thread.

Comment: That didn't work :/

I added : self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) and now it works but it's meh...